# Swiftui Reset Scrollview content and Foreach loop with a button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there any way to reset the scrollview or total app view including foreach loop with a reset button. I have following code which draws rectangles. Add amount and rotate. I want to reset all with a button click. Please help. This is a playground project.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]    
    @State private var Amout = 10
    @State private var angle = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(0..<20) { number in
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 80)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
                        .overlay(
                            Text("\(number)").foregroundColor(.white)
                        )
                        .onTapGesture {
                            Amout += number
                            angle += 5
                        }
                }
            }.padding(.all, 10)
            
            Text ("Total Amount is : \(Amout)")
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .bold()
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                
                // Help needed here :-) 
                    
                }  label: {
                    Text("Reset")
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    @State private var Amout = 10
    @State private var angle = 0.0
    
    @State var isVisible = false
    @State var resetButVisible = false
    @State var dealCardsVisible = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 80)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button("Deal Cards", action: {
                        
                        dealCardsVisible.toggle()
                        isVisible.toggle()
                        resetButVisible.toggle()
                        
                    })
                    
                    Spacer()
                }.opacity(dealCardsVisible ? 1:0)
                
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 15) {
                            ForEach(0..<20) { number in
                                
                                Rectangle()
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 80)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: 2, y: 2)
                                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(angle))
                                    .overlay(
                                        Text("\(number)").foregroundColor(.white)
                                    )
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        Amout += number
                                        angle += 5
                                    }
                            }
                }.padding(.all, 10)
                    .opacity(isVisible ? 1:0)
            }
                    
                    Text ("Total Amount is : \(Amout)")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                    
                    Button {
                        Amout = 10
                        angle = 0
                        
                        isVisible.toggle()
                        resetButVisible.toggle()
                        dealCardsVisible.toggle()
                        
                        }  label: {
                            Text("Reset")
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        }.opacity(resetButVisible ? 1:0)
                    
                }
            }
    }


struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test()
    }
}
```

its a little bit ugly but its work. I couldn't find what you want with lazyGrid. Maybe a little work that can seem good.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you mean with reseting foreach loop.

Comment: This is Great, Sorry I missed to ask that question. 1. Is there any way that each tile appear on load as one by one and when we click reset it appear again one by one like playing cards. Thanks

Comment: i edit the answer I hope that will help you.